# Authentication issues with apps script Web App

Tags: google-apps-script

I am in the process of developing a google apps script web app designed for school teachers and students. I have deployed a version of the web app with following settings:

Execute as: User accessing the web app
Who has access: Anyone with Google account

My intention is to make this app available to anyone with a google (gmail, or edu/org google account).

The app still has a Publishing status of 'Testing' in the 'OAuth consent screen' settings. I am trying to get a few users test this web app.

Users in my google domain all seem to be able go through the OAuth2 steps, and access it without issues.
Test users with @gmail.com accounts that I have added to the 'Test users' list in 'OAuth consent screen' settings are able to go through the OAuth2 steps, and access it without issues.

BUT, test users that I have added to the 'Test users' list in 'OAuth consent screen' settings that are google EDU domain accounts (not @gmail.com) can not seem to get past the OAuth2 steps they are presented with. I have two such users, from two different google EDU domains, and both have the same exact issue:

- Upon accessing the app URL, they are presented with a google sign in
  prompt.
- User clicks on "Review Permissions" to open the OAuth flow
  in a popup.
- User chooses/confirms the google EDU account they wish to
  use to sign in.
- Everything normal upto the above step, but on the
  next screen, they see this message and there is no way to proceed:

> Something went wrong
> Sorry, something went wrong there. Try again.

The url on the popup at this point starts with https://accounts.google.com/info/unknownerror?access_type=offline&login_hint=xxx

Scopes requested - if relavant:

```
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
```

My questions:

- How do I resolve this issue?
- Is this issue specific to just the 'Testing' status, or might this still be an issue with the app when it is published?

Comment: Can you provide more information about these `google EDU domain accounts`? How were they created?

Comment: Sorry - these are external users - so I do not have that information.

Answer (score 1):

Update: It appears that the issue goes away if I publish the app (in OAuth Consent screen settings).